# C# LINQ query to select only first date in a month from List<DateTime>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List which contains dates from June 1, 2009 to June 1, 2014.  How would I query it in C# LINQ to select only the first date of each month?

Comment: FYI, if it's querying objects, it's just LINQ, not LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Do you mean the first date in the list in each month or the first date in the month?

Comment: All great answers.  Very good approaches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way I think is to filter by the [Day](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day.aspx) property of your dates:

```
var firstDays = dates.Where(d=> d.Day == 1);
```

Comment: The wording of the question is horrible.  This is a great solution if you want the 1st of every month that appears in the list (e.g. 1st Jan, 1st Feb etc), but it won't work if you want the first date that appears in the list for each month (e.g. 2nd Jan if the 1st Jan is not in the list, etc)

Answer (score 9):

Your question is slightly ambiguous. If you want the first item *appearing in the list* in each month, you can use:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month })
                 .Select(x => x.Min());
```

Comment: That one is generic one,great.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
dates.Where(d => d.Day == 1);
```

Or, using query comprehension,

```
from d in dates where d.Day == 1 select d;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
public static bool IsFirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime t) {
  var other = new DateTime(t.Year,t.Month,1);
  return other == t.Date;
}

var allDates = GetTheDates();
var filter = allDates.Where(x => x.IsFirstDayOfMonth());
```